# How to scroll column so that all its children are brought into view?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I have a column which consists of multiple composables of one Text (For row title) and one lazyrow (For row items), for TV screens

For reference :

```
Column {
    AlignedRow(data)
}

fun AlignedRow(data) {
    if (data != null)
    Column {
        Text()
        LazyRow {
            items(data.rowList) {
                //add items
            }
        }
    }
```

While scrolling the parent column downwards, everything is as expected; but while scrolling back up, the top most *AlignedRow* only focusses on one of the child items at the top of the screen and thus the title text is left out of the screen?

How can I make this scroll work in a way so that when we scroll up both the lazyrow and the title text is rendered onto the screen? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a extension method on Modifier which will bring the entire item in view if any of its children is focused.

```
internal fun Modifier.bringIntoViewIfChildrenAreFocused(): Modifier = composed(
    inspectorInfo = debugInspectorInfo { name = "bringIntoViewIfChildrenAreFocused" },
    factory = {
        var myRect: Rect = Rect.Zero
        this
            .onSizeChanged {
                myRect = Rect(Offset.Zero, Offset(it.width.toFloat(), it.height.toFloat()))
            }
            .bringIntoViewResponder(
                remember {
                    object : BringIntoViewResponder {
                        // return the current rectangle and ignoring the child rectangle received.
                        @ExperimentalFoundationApi
                        override fun calculateRectForParent(localRect: Rect): Rect = myRect

                        // The container is not expected to be scrollable. Hence the child is
                        // already in view with respect to the container.
                        @ExperimentalFoundationApi
                        override suspend fun bringChildIntoView(localRect: () -> Rect?) {}
                    }
                }
            )
    }
)
```

Here is how you can use it:

```
Column {
    AlignedRow(data)
}

fun AlignedRow(data) {
    if (data != null)

    Column(Modifier.bringIntoViewIfChildrenAreFocused()) {
        Text()
        LazyRow {
            items(data.rowList) {
                //add items
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:tv/tv-material/src/main/java/androidx/tv/material3/BringIntoViewIfChildrenAreFocused.kt;l=32-55;drc=507211da0eac35ca8bde15524f50bfb06c98476b) from the official Compose for TV library

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `Text` composable inside the LazyRow

```
LazyRow {
    item {
        Text()
    }
    items(data.rowList) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't this put the text alongside all the other items in the row, I want it to be something like Text above and all the row items below it