# PiviotOffset of TvLazyColunm not working for nested lists

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I have a TvLazyColunm and inside that many TvLazyRows

```
            ComposeTvAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    TvLazyColumn(
                        pivotOffsets = PivotOffsets(parentFraction = 0f, childFraction = 0f),
                    ) {
                        items(count = 10) {
                            Column {
                                Spacer(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .background(Color.Yellow)
                                        .fillParentMaxWidth()
                                        .height(50.dp)
                                )
                                TvLazyRow(
                                    pivotOffsets = PivotOffsets(
                                        parentFraction = 0f,
                                        childFraction = 0f
                                    )
                                ) {
                                    items(10) {
                                        Card(
                                            colors = CardDefaults.colors(containerColor = Color.Transparent),
                                            onClick = { }) {
                                            Box(
                                                modifier = Modifier
                                                    .background(Color.Transparent)
                                                    .padding(60.dp)
                                                    .fillParentMaxWidth(0.2f)
                                                    .height(150.dp)
                                                    .background(
                                                        Color.Red
                                                    )
                                            )
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The issue is while focusing on the TvLazyRow item or the card the spacer i gave is hiding but i gave paremtFraction of TvLazyColunm as 0f so it should be visible but it is not.

Any way to solve this?

I tried changing parent fraction that worked but i had to test how much value i have to give but it is just a workaroung but not a solution.

Video Link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MHabJcsnBoDDoWXFh9qFMMQjIRm6D3-G/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [bringIntoViewIfChildrenAreFocused](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75855352/8822610) modifier. This modifier will bring the entire composable in view if any of the child Composables is focused.

Here is how you would use it:

```kotlin
Column(Modifier.bringIntoViewIfChildrenAreFocused()) {
    Spacer(...)

    TvLazyRow(...) {...}
}
```